# Pandas matching elements from the list

Tags: python, pandas

I need to match keywords listed in pandas column with the keywords from a list and create a new column that consists of matched words. Example:

```
my_list = ['machine learning', 'artificial intelligence', 'lasso']
```

Data:

```
listing                                         keyword_column
I am looking for machine learning expert        machine learning
Machine learning expert that knows lasso        machine learning, lasso
Need a web designer                              
Artificial Intelligence application on...       artificial intelligence
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) for get all values in list, join togehter by [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html) and if necessary convert to lowercase by [`Series.str.lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lower.html):

Also here are used word boundaries with `\b` for correct matching whole words from `my_list`.

```
my_list = ['machine learning', 'artificial intelligence', 'lasso']

import re

pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in my_list)
df['new'] = df['listing'].str.findall(pat, flags=re.I).str.join(', ').str.lower()
```

Or:

```
df['new'] = df['listing'].str.lower().str.findall(pat).str.join(', ')
```

---

```
print (df)
                                    listing           keyword_column  \
0  I am looking for machine learning expert         machine learning   
1  Machine learning expert that knows lasso  machine learning, lasso   
2                      Need a web designer                       NaN   
3    Artificial Intelligence application on  artificial intelligence   

                       new  
0         machine learning  
1  machine learning, lasso  
2                           
3  artificial intelligence
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `str.lower` + `str.findall` + `str.join` to solve your problem:

```
df['keyword_column'] = df['listing'].str.lower().str.findall('|'.join(my_list)).str.join(', ')
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Is:

```
                                     listing           keyword_column
0   I am looking for machine learning expert         machine learning
1   Machine learning expert that knows lasso  machine learning, lasso
2                        Need a web designer                         
3  Artificial Intelligence application on...  artificial intelligence
```

Answer (score 1):

flashtext can also be used to extract keyword

```
import pandas as pd
from flashtext import KeywordProcessor

data = ['I am looking for machine learning expert','Machine learning expert that knows lasso ','Need a web designer','Artificial Intelligence application on...' ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['listing'])
my_list = ['machine learning', 'artificial intelligence', 'lasso']

kp = KeywordProcessor()
kp.add_keywords_from_list(my_list)

df['keyword_columns'] = df['listing'].apply(lambda x: kp.extract_keywords(x))

#op
df['keyword_columns']
Out[68]: 
0           [machine learning]
1    [machine learning, lasso]
2                           []
3    [artificial intelligence]
```